# Using an event added to several programatically created controls

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I display the stock of items composing a product, the user must be able to update the sizes and quantities of these items in a DataGridView for each item after selecting a product.

I create the DataGridViews and event allowing to update the database programatically because each product can be composed of 1 up to 5 items.

```
SqlCommand stockCommand;
SqlDataAdapter stockAdapter;
SqlCommandBuilder stockBuilder;
DataSet stockDs;
DataTable stockTable;

private void DisplayItems()
{
    string queryItems = "SELECT id_item, id_PF, Name, Type FROM Items WHERE id_PF = "+ PF_id + " AND Type = 'BE'";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStringLocal))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdStock = new SqlCommand(queryItems, con))
        {
        int i = 0;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader readerStock = cmdStock.ExecuteReader();

        while (readerStock.Read())
        {
            string itemName = readerStock["Name"].ToString();
        DisplayItemsStock(i, itemName);
        i++;
        }
    }
    }
}


private void DisplayItemsStock(int i, string item)
{
    DataGridView stock = new DataGridView();
    stock.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(stock_KeyDown);

    string queryItemStock = "SELECT id_stock, item_name, size, quantity FROM Stock WHERE item_name = '" + item + "'";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStringLocal);
    stockCommand = new SqlCommand(queryItemStock con);
    stockAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(stockCommand);
    stockBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(stockAdapter);
    stockDs = new DataSet();
    stockAdapter.Fill(stockDs, "stock");
    stockTable = stockDs.Tables["stock"];
    con.Close();
    stock.DataSource = stockTable;

    panelStock.Controls.Add(stock);
}

private void stock_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView stock = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (e.Keycode == Keys.Enter)
    {
    // Check different conditions and update if everything is good

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStringLocal))
        {
        con.Open();
        stockAdapter.Update(stockTable);
        MessageBox.Show("Saved changes");
    }       
    }
}
```

The Update command only happens on the last created DataGridView when I need it to work on all of them.

Comment: I don't see the `DataGridView` control being added anywhere to the form?

Comment: @gunnerone I did not think it was relevant to the question, I edited my code.

Comment: @A.Petit - You should read [ask] and then [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're encountering this issue because these variables are shared among your `DataGridViews`.

```
SqlCommand stockCommand;
SqlDataAdapter stockAdapter;
SqlCommandBuilder stockBuilder;
DataSet stockDs;
DataTable stockTable;
```

For example when the `DataGridView` is created for the first item, `stockCommand` is set to a new `SqlCommand` using the query for that item.  And the adapter, builder, dataset, and table are created from this as well.  The problem then arises when a `DataGridView` is created for the next item.  Now a new `stockCommand` object is created with the query for the next item.  And similarly the adapter, builder, dataset, and table are all set to new objects for the next item.  They're no longer using the query for the first item.

Now when the key down event happens it uses `stockTable` and `stockAdapter` which are now using the query for the last item.  Hence the last item is the only one that gets updated.

You can avoid this problem by creating and keeping separate command, adapter, builder, dataset, and datatable variables for each `DataGridView`.  You could do this with a `Dictionary` or I did it with a new class.

```
public class StockItem
{
  private const string conStringLocal = "Data Source=TestDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;";

  private readonly SqlCommand stockCommand;
  private readonly SqlDataAdapter stockAdapter;
  private readonly SqlCommandBuilder stockBuilder;
  private readonly DataSet stockDs;
  private readonly DataTable stockTable;

  public DataGridView StockDataGridView { get; }

  public StockItem(string item)
  {
    StockDataGridView = new DataGridView();
    StockDataGridView.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(stock_KeyDown);

    string queryItemStock = "SELECT id_stock, item_name, size, quantity "
      + "FROM Stock WHERE item_name = '" + item + "'";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStringLocal);

    stockCommand = new SqlCommand(queryItemStock, con);
    stockAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(stockCommand);
    stockBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(stockAdapter);
    stockDs = new DataSet();
    stockAdapter.Fill(stockDs, "Stock");
    stockTable = stockDs.Tables["Stock"];
    con.Close();
    StockDataGridView.DataSource = stockTable;
  }

  private void stock_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    DataGridView stock = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
      // Check different conditions and update if everything is good
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStringLocal))
      {
        con.Open();

        stockAdapter.Update(stockTable);
        MessageBox.Show("Saved changes");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `DisplayItems` function stays the same.  And `DisplayItemsStock` becomes:

```
private void DisplayItemsStock(int i, string item)
{
  StockItem stockItem = new StockItem(item);
  panelStock.Controls.Add(stockItem.StockDataGridView);
}
```